# Improve rate estimates of geo. events by other attributes?

Tags: geostatistics

I have somewhat rare events (at given times) at geographical locations. I also have a lot of static data about each micro-region. Some of the static data is likely to be correlated with the true event rates. I'm interested in the event rates for all regions (at any acceptable aggregate level), where the regions should be as small as possible without introducing too much uncertainty in the rate estimation.

Is there a way to make use of the static data to get more accurate estimates of the event rate per region? How can I determine the acceptable granularity of the region?

Any ideas, approaches or references?